# Runtime Error signal 11 on simple C++ code

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error, breadth-first-search

I am getting a runtime error with this code and I have no idea why.
I am creating a grid and then running a BFS over it. The objective here is to read in the rows and columns of the grid, then determine the maximum number of stars you can pass over before reaching the end.
The start is the top left corner and the end is the bottom right corner.
You can only move down and right. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int r, c, stars[1001][1001], grid[1001][1001], ns[1001][1001];
    pair<int, int> cr, nx;
    char tmp;
    queue<pair<int, int> > q;
    cin >> r >> c;

    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            cin >> tmp;

            if(tmp == '.') {
                grid[i][j] = 1000000000;
                ns[i][j] = 0;
                stars[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else if(tmp == '*') {
                grid[i][j] = 1000000000;
                ns[i][j] = 1;
                stars[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else
                grid[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    grid[0][0] = 0;
    cr.first = 0;
    cr.second = 0;
    q.push(cr);

    while(!q.empty()) {
        cr = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if(cr.first < r - 1 && grid[cr.first + 1][cr.second] != -1 && ns[cr.first][cr.second] + stars[cr.first + 1][cr.second] > ns[cr.first + 1][cr.second]) {
            nx.first = cr.first + 1; nx.second = cr.second;

            grid[nx.first][nx.second] = grid[cr.first][cr.second] + 1;
            ns[nx.first][nx.second] = ns[cr.first][cr.second] + stars[cr.first + 1][cr.second];
            q.push(nx);
        }

        if(cr.second < c - 1 && grid[cr.first][cr.second + 1] != -1 && ns[cr.first][cr.second] + stars[cr.first][cr.second + 1] > ns[cr.first][cr.second + 1]) {
            nx.first = cr.first; nx.second = cr.second + 1;

            grid[nx.first][nx.second] = grid[cr.first][cr.second] + 1;
            ns[nx.first][nx.second] = ns[cr.first][cr.second] + stars[cr.first][cr.second + 1];
            q.push(nx);
        }
    }

    if(grid[r - 1][c - 1] == 1000000000)
        cout << "Impossible" << endl;
    else
        cout << ns[r - 1][c - 1] << endl;
}
```

Sample input :

```
6 7
.#*..#.
..*#...
#.....#
..###..
..##..*
*#.....
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your stack is not big enough for

```
int stars[1001][1001], grid[1001][1001], ns[1001][1001];
```

which is `3 * 1001 * 1001 * sizeof(int)` bytes. That's ~12MB if the size of `int` is 4 bytes.

Either increase the stack size with a compiler option, or go with dynamic allocation i.e. `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the large stack you should allocate on the heap

Since you seem to have three parallel 2 - dimension arrays you could
maybe create struct that contains all three values for a x,y position.
That would make it easier to maintain:

---

```
struct Area 
{ 
  int grid; 
  int ns; 
  int stars; 
}; 
std::vector<std::array<Area,1001>> dim2(1001);
dim2[x][y].grid = 100001;
...
```

---